# Segamentation fault encountered while parsing contents of string separated by a delimiter

Tags: c, split, segmentation-fault, c-strings, function-definition

During an interview, I was asked to implement a solution for following problem in C programming language:

Given an input string with a fixed pattern of contents separated by a delimiter, I need to extract each specific content.

Pattern of input string: "starting_message|integer_value_1|integer_value_2|character_code|ending_message"

Expected output:

```
Starting message: starting_message
Value 1 : integer_value_1
Value 2 : integer_value_2
Char code : character_code
Ending message : ending_message
```

Example input: "HelloWorld|35|45|C|ByeWorld"

Example output:

```
Starting message: HelloWorld
Value 1 : 35
Value 2 : 45
Char code : C
Ending message : ByeWorld
```

I implemented the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
/*
Loop through the input string until termination.
Figure out the position of delimiters first. It will help in parsing later.
For string, count the number of chars and use memcpy for that number of elements.
To parse char to int, try atoi.
*/

void parse(const char* input, char* starting_message, int* value1, int* value2, char* char_code, char* ending_message)
{
  int ctr = 0, pos_ctr=0;
  int delim_pos[4];  /* To store the location of delimiters aka '|' */
  
  char* value1_str = (char*) malloc(10);
  char* value2_str = (char*) malloc(10);
  
  while(input[ctr]!= '\0')
  {
    if(input[ctr] == '|')
    {
      if(pos_ctr < 4)
      {
        delim_pos[pos_ctr] = ctr;
        pos_ctr++;
      }
    }
    ctr++;
  }
  
  memcpy(starting_message,input,(delim_pos[0]));  /* starting_message is contained in input string in between input[0] & input[delim_pos[0]]*/
  starting_message[delim_pos[0]+1] = '\0';
  
  memcpy(value1_str, input,(delim_pos[1]-delim_pos[0]));   /* value1 is contained in input string in between input[delim_pos[0]] & input[delim_pos[1]]*/
  value1_str[(delim_pos[1]-delim_pos[0] + 1)] = '\0';
  *value1 = atoi(value1_str);
  
  memcpy(value2_str, input,(delim_pos[2]-delim_pos[1]));   /* value2 is contained in input string in between input[delim_pos[1]] & input[delim_pos[2]]*/
  value1_str[(delim_pos[2]-delim_pos[1] + 1)] = '\0';
  *value2 = atoi(value2_str);
  
  *char_code = input[(delim_pos[2]+1)];     /* char_code is element next to input[delim_pos[2]]*/
  
  memcpy(ending_message, input, (delim_pos[3]-ctr-1));  /* ending_message is contained in input string in between input[delim_pos[3]] & null termination char*/
  ending_message[delim_pos[3]-ctr] = '\0';
  
}


int main() {

const char* input = "HelloWorld|35|45|C|ByeWorld";
char* starting_message = (char*) malloc(30);
char* ending_message = (char*) malloc(30);
int value1, value2;
char char_code;

parse(input, starting_message, &value1, &value2, &char_code, ending_message);


printf(" Input string: %s\n",input);
printf("Starting message : %s\n", starting_message);
printf("Value 1 : %d\n", value1);
printf("Value 2 : %d\n", value2);
printf("Character code : %c\n", char_code);
printf("Ending message: %s\n", ending_message);

    return 0;
}
```

I was able to compile but on the output screen, I encountered a segmentation fault with no output.

[image: Output screen]

Where did I go wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: My advice: never do any tests in an interview. The interview is not an exam. It is a conversation.:)

Comment: Note that there is no need to allocate buffers for the strings passed to `atoi`. It can be called directly on the input string (plus the offset to the first character of the value). E.g. `*value1 = atoi(&input[delim_pos[0]+1]);`.

Comment: @Kshitij_9192 As for the function then the function does not make a great sense.  For example the function does not report whether the processing was successful or not.

Comment: Another bug is that all the `memcpy` calls are copying from the start of the input string.

Comment: @Kshitij_9192 These memory allocations char* value1_str = (char*) malloc(10);
  char* value2_str = (char*) malloc(10); are redundant. And moreover the function produces memory leaks.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the function does not report whether parsing of the input string was successful.

The function has too many parameters. Instead of this list of parameters

```
char* starting_message, int* value1, int* value2, char* char_code, char* ending_message
```

you could pass an object of a structure type. For example the function declaration could be

```
int parse( const char *input, struct Fields *fields );
```

These memory allocations

```
char* value1_str = (char*) malloc(10);
char* value2_str = (char*) malloc(10)
```

are redundant and moreover due to these allocations the function produces memory leaks.

Instead of the function `atoi` you should use the function `strtol`.

Instead of this while loop

```
while(input[ctr]!= '\0')
```

you could use a loop within which there is called the function `strchr`.

In this assignment

```
starting_message[delim_pos[0]+1] = '\0';
```

the character at the position `delim_pos[0]` can have indeterminate value. Instead of the statement above you have to write

```
starting_message[delim_pos[0]] = '\0';
```

In these statements

```
memcpy(value1_str, input,(delim_pos[1]-delim_pos[0]));
memcpy(value2_str, input,(delim_pos[2]-delim_pos[1]));
memcpy(ending_message, input, (delim_pos[3]-ctr-1));
```

you are copying characters beginning from the start  of the string `input` that does not make a sense. Moreover this expression `delim_pos[3]-ctr-1` will yield a negative value.

This statement

```
ending_message[delim_pos[3]-ctr] = '\0';
```

invokes undefined behavior because the value of the expression `delim_pos[3]-ctr` is negative. `ctr` stores the length of the input string.

Thus the function has undefined behavior and does not make a great sense.:)

Comment: Thanks @Vlad for such a detailed explanation and the scope of improvement in this program. Through your detailed comments, I was able to understand that this program is a blunder. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your segmentation fault occurs here:

```
memcpy(ending_message, input, (delim_pos[3]-ctr-1));
```

Typical causes for segmentation faults are null or garbage pointers, but here, it's something else: You have miscalculated the number of bytes to copy, because you got the subtraction the wrong way round. It should be

```
ctr + 1 - delim_pos[3]
```

because, if everything went well, `str` is past `delim_pos[3]`. (But you don't check that `pos_ctr == 4`, so you don't know whether everything went well.)

The third parameter to `memcpy` is of the unsigned integer type `size_t`. By mixing up the subtraction, you got a small negative `int` value, which will be a huge positive value when converted to an unsigned value, which certainly leads to out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Thanks @M Oehm , it was a silly mistake on my side.